# ctime gives incorrect output

Tags: c, linux

[**ctime()**](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/ctime.3.html) function is supposed to give the time in string format since Epoch for the seconds passed in. This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(int argc, int **argv)
{
    time_t tmp=86400; // Seconds for one day
    char *s;
    s = ctime(&tmp);
    if(!s) perror("ctime");
    else printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

The program gives correct output on my Ubuntu 12.04, 32 bit machine:

```
Fri Jan  2 01:00:00 1970
```

But the same code gives wrong output on my Scientific Linux, 64-bit machine:

```
Thu Jan  1 16:00:00 1970
```

Apparently, according to this machine Epoch is:

```
Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 1969
```

Any idea why Scientific Linux 6 is giving wrong output?!

Comment: Can you add to what timezones these machines are set?

Comment: Do you have different values for the TZ environment variable on the two machines?

Comment: Yes, the local time matters! `ctime()` gives you a string representing the local time, which is not UTC unless your time zone happens to be UTC.  Try setting the `$TZ` environment variable to `UTC` before running your program; that should give you consistent results.

Comment: There are ways other than `$TZ` to set the timezone. Typically something like `/etc/timezone` determines the default timezone when `$TZ` isn't set. Setting `$TZ` will override that for the current process. Setting `$TZ` to either `UTC` or the empty string should set your time zone to UTC.

Comment: @KingsIndian actually no, because UTC doesn't observe DST whereas UK local does, so UK localtime is only equal to UTC during part of the year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `time_t` value always [1] represents the number of seconds since the epoch, which is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC -- plus or minus whatever handwaving is required to acknowledge that we're probably ignoring leap seconds.  So `(time_t)86400` represents a single moment in time, regardless of your current time zone.

The `ctime()` function returns a pointer to an awkwardly formatted[2] string expressed in *local* time.  I'm 8 hours west of UTC, so on my system your program's output is:

```
Thu Jan  1 16:00:00 1970
```

(the epoch plus 24 hours from your `86400`, minus 8 hours for my time zone).

A system's idea of the current time zone can be determined in any of several ways. On my Ubuntu system, `/etc/timezone` contains the line `America/Los_Angeles`. On CentOS, which should be similar to Scientific Linux, `/etc/localtime` is a binary timezone data file.

On both systems, the system default time zone can be overridden by setting the `$TZ` environment variable, with `UTC` or the empty string denoting UTC.  If I set `$TZ` to either `UTC` or `""`, your program's output is:

```
Fri Jan  2 00:00:00 1970
```

The epoch is always the same moment in history, but it can be expressed differently.  For example (using the GNU Coreutils `date` command, showing the epoch itself rather than 24 hours after the epoch as your program does):

```
$ date -d @0
Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1969
$ date -u -d @0
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970
$ TZ=UTC date -d @0
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970
$ TZ= date -d @0
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970
$
```

Note that if you're in the UK, your local time matches UTC only part of the year.

[1] Well, nearly always.  POSIX guarantees that a `time_t` value represents seconds since the epoch, but the C standard says only that it's an arithmetic type capable of representing times.  And you can store any value you like in a `time_t` object, and have it mean whatever you like, but all the standard C and POSIX functions that deal with `time_t` values treat them as seconds since the epoch.

[2] The format produced by `ctime()` and `asctime()` is rather awkward, for historical reasons. It's of the form `Sun Sep 16 01:03:52 1973\n\0`. Note the lack of any time zone information; also the trailing `'\n'` can be confusing (I've seen extraneous blank lines in log files because of it). The [`strftime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) function gives you a lot more flexibility. I recommend using [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

the number of seconds should be in UTC - number of seconds elapsed since 00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC

Look at the description for time_t:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/

Answer (score 1):

The manual page you refer to says

> The ctime(), gmtime() and localtime() functions all take an argument of data
>   type time_t which represents **calendar time**.  When interpreted as an absolute
>   time value, it represents the number of seconds elapsed since the Epoch,
>   1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).

And this [some ctime implementation](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-186/gen.subproj/ctime.c)

```
char *
ctime(timep)
const time_t * const    timep;
{
    return asctime(localtime(timep));
}
```

As you can see, it uses localtime, ie time relative to timezone of the current process.

Comment: Relative to the *current process's* timezone.